# Revert Windows Azure App Service to original/default state

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a Azure App Service (Windows OS, F1 pricing tier), which I seem to have broken (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69658465/error-on-windows-azure-app-service-please-install-sqlite3-package-manually/69669446#69669446) for details).

I was hoping I could just start over, and reset the VM back to its original state, but for the life of me, I can't find any way to do that. I've tried searching StackOverflow and the web in general but haven't come across a solution to this seemingly simple problem.

I could delete and recreate the App Service, but when I've attempted this in the past, I've had to use a new name (i.e., I lost my original *.azurewebsites.net URL).

I'd be happy with a solution that either resets the service back to default or lets me recreate the service but with same name and URL. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this isn't quite a full reset, but simply clearing out all the files in home > site > wwwroot using the console solved my issue.